# error case_when ! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new column (age_clean) based on data in 2 columns: age (numeric) and age_unit (days, weeks, months, years).

If the age is between 0-<1 OR age unit equals weeks OR days or age is between 0-11 with unit months, have age_clean = 0.

Here is my code:

```
database %>%
  mutate(age_clean = 
           case_when(!age_unit %in% c("years", "days", "months", "weeks") ~ "Other",
                     (age >= 0  & age < 1) | (age_unit == "weeks" | age_unit == "days") | (age >= 0  & age <= 11 & age_unit == "months") ~ '0',
                     TRUE ~ as.numeric(age)))
    
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `age_clean = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `` names(message) <- `*vtmp*` ``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Note that for some of the rows, there is no data in age or age_unit. Maybe I am missing a clause for NA?

Comment: `case_when()` requires all conditions to return the same type.  Here you have it returning numeric in the last condition where all other conditions return character.  Use `as.character(age)` in the last condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you overcomplicate your cases though, but I am not 100% sure if I understand you well. I assume you want "age_clean" to be an age in years? If so you can do it this way.

```
library(dplyr)

database %>% 
  mutate(
    age = as.numeric(age),
    age_clean = case_when(
      age_unit == "years" ~ age,
      age_unit == "months" ~ age %/% 12,
      age_unit == "weeks" ~ age %/% 52,
      age_unit == "days" ~ age %/% 365,
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
  ))
```

Or you can use this instead of using cases at all:

```
mutate(age_clean = floor(as.numeric(duration(age, units = age_unit), "years")))
```

**results**

```
#   age age_unit age_clean
# 1   2    years         2
# 2  18    years        18
# 3 100     days         0
# 4 380     days         1
# 5  10   months         0
# 6  26   months         2
# 7  25    weeks         0
# 8  54    weeks         1
```

**data**

```
database <- data.frame(
  age = c(2, 18, 100, 380, 10, 26, 25, 54),
  age_unit = c("years", "years", "days", "days", "months", "months", "weeks", "weeks")
)
```

Comment: Thanks Merjin- I was using code from another project so probably overcomplicated for this method. I tried your first example with the years, months, weeks, days on different lines, but then I get the error again:

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `age_clean = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `` names(message) <- `*vtmp*` ``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Do I need a line for those with no data in age or age_unit?

Comment: I updated my answer, I forgot `TRUE ~ NA_real_` this part, now it also works when age or age_unit is missing or if the units are not in the cases.

Comment: Still not working :( It works with your example dataset, but not with my actual data. This is the dataframe with my actual data: databse <- data.frame(
  age = c(" ", 12, 14, " ", 12, 13),
  age_unit = c(" ", "years", "years", " ", "months", "days")
)

I'm using " " to represent no data/blank entry

Comment: having a space in age makes them of type character, I assumed it to be numeric, added the conversion in my answer

Comment: That worked and now I understand how the blanks are categorized. Thanks!